# LIBGDX Animate without enternig render()

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to make an actor move from one point to another in a method.

```
    int i=0;
    while(i<20){
        actor.get(nb).moveBy(rx, ry);
        //Wait
        long ti = System.nanoTime();
        while((System.nanoTime()-ti)<50000000){}
        i++;
    }
```

But when it happens the animation doesn't shows until the actor is on the final point, because it's not going to the render method until this method is finished.

Is there a wayto make the animation happen without goning to the render method?

Answer (score 2):

You should read more about libgdx and how it's architecture works. [The life cycle](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/The-life-cycle).

What you are doing there is active waiting and that's something you should **NEVER** do. The `render()` method actually gets a `float` value which is called `deltaTime`. This is the amount of time it took the last frame to render. You can use this value to update your actors position, based on the time that has passed.

```
actor.get(nb).moveBy(rx * deltaTime, ry * deltaTime);
```

That way you would move your actor by (rx, ry) in 1 second. If you want it to happen in 2 seconds, you should decrease the speed.

```
actor.get(nb).moveBy(rx / 2 * deltaTime, ry / 2 * deltaTime);
```

That way you do not completely block your program with active waiting, but you move the actor according to the time that has passed. Then it will be rendered and with the next call to `render(deltaTime)`, which libgdx will do right after, you will do the same again, until you have reached your destination. That has to be handled differently, because otherwise your actor would never stop moving. You can do that with a simple `if` statement which will stop the actor from moving from a certain point on.

```
if (actor.getPosition().x < 10, actor.getPosition().y < 15) {
     actor.get(nb).moveBy(rx / 2 * deltaTime, ry / 2 * deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to animate an [Actor](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html), use the [Actions](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/Actions.html) class like this :

```
actor.addAction(Actions.moveTo(newX, newY, duration))
```

Also add you Actor to a Stage and call [Stage#act()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.html#act%28%29) in the Application#render() method... all the magic of translating the actor depending on the delta time will be handled for you... read more on the stage wiki of the project site here : https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d